# Why is this code not printing the lower-case alphabet as expected?

Tags: c

The problem is asking to fill an array with lowercase letters and then print them. What I'm getting as output are uppercase starting with F and going 5 places past Z. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{   
    char alphabet[27];
    char i;

    for(i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        printf("%c", &alphabet[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never filled your array with anything. Also, check your code using the preview pane before submitting

Comment: `i` is the character you want to print. `alphabet[i]` and `&alphabet[i]` are nonsense.

Comment: You never initialized `alphabet`, and even if you had, you would be using the wrong indices, and taking the *addresses* of the elements is completely wrong.

Comment: It's out of bound access. The value of `'a'` is `97` while while the array is only 27 characters long.

Comment: just wondering - why alphabet is `[27]`?

Comment: @Lashane: 26 letters plus terminating null, though the terminal null isn't critical since the array isn't being treated as a string.

Comment: You're passing the addresses of successive elements way beyond the end of the `alphabet` array, and those addresses happen to be such that when the low-order byte is printed via `"%c"`, the values end with 0x70, 0x71, ….  This assumes you're on a little-endian machine; you'd see different behaviour on a big-endian machine.  The code's behaviour is undefined; you get what you get.  Getting what you want is easy enough when you think about it accurately — hint, `i` contains the character code for the letters `a` through `z` on successive iterations of the loop.

Comment: @Lashane... Jonathon beat me to it... i was thinking I needed to make room for the terminating \0 at the end of the array. Soundz like I don't. :)

Comment: @Jonathan leffler and M.M... Thank you for the heads up and for cleaning up my mess. Don't quite know how that all happened. I get that i is each letter as it goez through its iterations but I'm not getting how I can get the loop to throw them into the array induces. I thought I was doing that with alphabet[i] but I see that that is pure rubbish. And I also see that &alphabet[] is for scant() not printf()... Oopz!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your codes.

1. You never initialize `char alphabet[27]`. You will never get what you want it you are initializing it.
2. Assume you initialize it, you can do the following

   `for(i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
       printf("%c", &alphabet[i - 'a']);`
3. If you just want to print the alphabet, you can just simply do the following:

   `for(i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
       printf("%c", i);`

Comment: *"Assume you initialize it, you can do the following ... `printf("%c", &alphabet[i - 'a']);`"*.You are printing address with `%c`. That's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'a' is 97. What you want to do is set i to 0 initially. Look here:
http://www.asciitable.com/.

Also, you want to add values to your array before using it in the loop. Something like this:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < 26) {
    alphabet[index] = index + 'a'; //or alphabet[index] = index + 97
    ++index;
}
```

Comment: I feel like the comment is superfluous, magic numbers are just silly to use. Also, using `27` will run you one off the end of the alphabet according to ascii, I don't _think_ char sets are guaranteed to have alpha chars ordered with decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code implements what is asked for — fill an array with the letters of the alphabet and then print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char alphabet[27];
    int i;

    for (i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        alphabet[i - 'a'] = i;
    alphabet[i - 'a'] = '\0';
    printf("alphabet: %s\n", alphabet);

    return 0;
}
```

*(Incidentally, I check these things before I post them, and in this case, I'm very glad I did.  I originally had `alphabet[i] = '\0';` after the loop, but this is reported as `error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]` — and that's right!  Even simple code that "can't go wrong" can go wrong.  My GCC 7.1.0 command line — which works with many other versions of GCC, was: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition x3.c -o x3`.  I recommend using most of those options — at minimum, use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.)*

This is similar to the code in the question, but probably isn't the way I'd actually write the code, in part because of the gotcha that nearly got me.

Another way of doing it would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char alphabet[26];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        alphabet[i] = i + 'a';
    printf("alphabet: %.*s\n", 26, alphabet);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `alphabet` is not a string; it is not null-terminated.  The `%.*s` conversion specification in conjunction with the `26` argument ensures that at most 26 characters are printed; it doesn't matter that `alphabet` is not a string.  Of course, using a slightly larger array and `alphabet[i] = '\0';` after the loop — analogous to the other code — would also work cleanly without the extra complexity in the `printf()` format string.

Left to my own devices, I'd probably use the null-terminating version of the second example program.

Read the POSIX specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for the details.  It does have some (clearly marked) extensions over standard C `printf()`, but it serves for both POSIX and standard C.  Then re-read it.  And re-re-read it.  And do that daily for a week, and then weekly for a month, and then monthly for a year, and then yearly ever after.  It will repay the effort.  And similarly for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html), which is even harder to use right than `printf()`.

Comment: Thank you for the education and reading rec. Much appreciated!  Don't quite get the wildcard format specified in printf() but I have seen. The reading you pointed to will help. I picked up a newer  "C Primer" 6th ed by Prada and watch whatever tutorialz I can find on this site,  cprogramming site and Youtube lecturez.  Things have changed since the last times I played with programming... rem's, goto's, and ?'s for print outout on an apple IIe in the early 80'z then later in 90 back in college...man... I truly underestimated Moore's law! At any rate... Thank you again for the help!