# Saving from a linked list to a file and loading it back

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I'm having trouble loading from a file into a linked list, been trying the whole day

first of all this is my struct

```
typedef struct Sensor {
    int id;
    int intervalo;
    char local[30];
    char tipo[30];
    //bool active;
    int active;
    struct Sensor* anterior;
    struct Sensor* proximo;
} Sensor;
```

this is my save function which i think its working fine, since the file gets created and the content is there.

```
void gravaLista(Sensor* l) {
    FILE *ficheiro;
    Sensor* temp = l;
    ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "r+t");

    if (ficheiro == NULL) {
        ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "w+t");
    }

    while (temp != NULL) {
        fprintf(ficheiro, "%d%d%d%30s%30s", temp->id, temp->intervalo, temp->active,
        temp->local, temp->tipo);
        temp = temp->proximo;
    }

    fclose(ficheiro);
}
```

now where i cant seem to make this work regardless of what i read about it is the load function.

heres what i have atm

```
int CarregaTodos(Sensor** l) {
    Sensor sens;
    FILE *ficheiro;
    int i = 0;

    ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "r+t");

    if (ficheiro == NULL) {
        printf("no file\n", "sensores.txt");
        return i;
    }

    rewind(ficheiro);
    while (fscanf(ficheiro, "%d%d%d%30s%30s", &sens.id, &sens.intervalo, &sens.active,
            &sens.local, &sens.tipo) == 5) {

            //novo() function returns a pointer to a new element and insereSensor adds the new element to the last position of the list
            insereSensorFim(&l, novo(sens.id, sens.intervalo, sens.local, sens.tipo));                              //this function inserts the new element at the end of the list
    }

    fclose(ficheiro);
    return i;
}
```

the helper functions work fine outside of the load function, but when i try to print the list after loading nothing gets printed. what am i missing?

edit: ill just post the helper functions too

```
Sensor* novo(int id, int tempo, char* l, char* t) {

    Sensor* novoSensor = (Sensor*)malloc(sizeof(struct Sensor));

    //novoSensor->id = ++(*totalSens);
    novoSensor->id = id;
    novoSensor->intervalo = tempo;
    strcpy(novoSensor->local, l);
    strcpy(novoSensor->tipo, t);
    novoSensor->active = 1;
    novoSensor->anterior = NULL;
    novoSensor->proximo = NULL;

    //gravaSensor(novoSensor, (*totalSens), 1);

    return novoSensor;
}

void insereSensorFim(Sensor** Lista, Sensor* novo) {

    Sensor* atual = *Lista;

    if ((*Lista == NULL))
        (*Lista = novo);

    else {

        while (atual->proximo != NULL) {
            atual = atual->proximo;
        }

        atual->proximo = novo;
        novo->anterior = atual;
    }
}
```

edit2: its fixed now, thanks to everyone who commented, you can read all the comments or just https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078897/8038340

Comment: You are missing a debugger?

Comment: If you write to file with `fprintf(ficheiro, "%d%d%d%30s%30s", temp->id, temp->intervalo, temp->active, temp->local, temp->tipo);`, how do you expect to separate the numbers again?

Comment: Are you sure your teacher did suggest `fwrite` instead of `fprintf`? Additionally, when writing `struct` to binary, to make it portable, you need to *serialize* the output. If you are just doing this for a learning exercise, then a direct write is fine without worrying about padding/packing differences between compilers, etc..

Comment: alright im a bit lost. since im providing the formatting "%d%d%d%30s%30s" in both load and save, shouldnt it work?

Comment: You can write it out that way, the problem is on the read. If you write `fprintf (fp, "%d", 2);` then the file contains `2`. How do you distinguish that from `23456`??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin im writing with fprintf. i could provide the code im basing mine on if helpful.

Comment: You need a *delimiter* between the `int` values to separate them. (e.g., a `space` or `comma` or `fixed-width` will work).

Comment: I would use a `space` or `comma`, so you can read one line per-struct and then simply parse each line of input. (**note:** if you write the structs out in binary, then you can rely on `2` being written as `4-bytes` (or whatever `int` is on your system)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ok so i changed fprintf to `fprintf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s;%29s", etc`
and the same for the fscanf
but its still not printing anything

Comment: Much better, now you have a way of distinguishing each `int` on the read. (also, if you wrap your inline-code in *backticks* (e.g. `\``) it will be formatted as code in your comments `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my fscanf looks like this now `fscanf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s\0;%29s\0"` but it still doesnt work. what am i missing?
would it help if i showed the helper functions?

Comment: `%29s\0` there is no need for `'\0'`, using the `%s` *format specifier*, you are already writing out a nul-terminated string. You cannot write a literal `nul` (which is just `0` and a non-printable ASCII character) to a formatted file. (can your strings contain `';'`, if so, then you need to find another string delimiter `'|'` maybe?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i just tried with both `'|'` and a space and nothing gets printed. im deleting the file and creating a new one everytime i change my fscanf and fprintf. also added the helper functions to the original post, maybe there's something wrong with them

Comment: If you specified the sizes completely, you could print using `"%11d%11d%11d%30.30s%30.30s"` — assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`. The string fields would include trailing spaces. On input, you'd then use `"%11d%11d%11d%30c%30c"`, noting that `%30c` would (a) include the trailing spaces and (b) not null terminate the input (but you can add the null easily enough, and must to treat the input as a string).  It's better to use an 'end of record' marker; the newline is the traditional and obvious character to use.  If you have newlines in your strings, you have to work harder!  This is modestly complex.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i removed the `&` on `insereSensorFim(&l, novo(sens.id, sens.intervalo, sens.local, sens.tipo)); `

and it seems to be working now! although i dont understand why. also changed to `\n` to separate the variables like this `"%d\n%d\n%d\n%29s\n%29s\n"`

Comment: If you're OK with each field on a line of its own, that's fine.  It works, and is reliable.  You're making sure that the fields are properly separated; that's what's important, and except that he's using `;` instead of `\n`, it's what @SiggiSv suggests in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44077839/).  (And I should have used `%29.29s` in my suggestion since your structure members are `char[29]` type.)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) properly is surprisingly hard.  It's possible to do all sorts of magic with them, but you need to know how they work to be able to perform that magic.

In the example code, you make life more difficult for yourself by not including a record delimiter in the output.  A newline is the conventional and simplest delimiter, but you can choose others if you wish, or no delimiter.  However, if you choose no delimiter, you have to know information about the data that is not given in the question.  If the strings never contain spaces, you can be less stringent in your formatting.  But you must have some way of knowing where one number ends and the next one starts — you can't simply smush all the numbers together as the sample `printf()` format does unless they're all negative, or you add a plus sign to the positive number (`%+d`).  There has to be some way to tell `scanf()` when to stop reading one and start on the next number.

This code is an elaboration of what I wrote in numerous comments.  The output format uses fixed width fields; this makes it easier to read them.  It does not assume there are no spaces in the strings, so it uses `%29c` to read 29 characters, and adds a null-terminator and removes trailing blanks via `strip_blanks()`.  It includes code to print lists; it uses that code.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Sensor
{
    int id;
    int intervalo;
    char local[30];
    char tipo[30];
    int active;
    struct Sensor *anterior;
    struct Sensor *proximo;
} Sensor;

static void insereSensorFim(Sensor **Lista, Sensor *novo);
static Sensor *novoSensor(int id, int tempo, char *l, char *t);

static const char *outfile = "sensores.txt";

static
void gravaLista(Sensor *l)
{
    FILE *ficheiro = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (ficheiro == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", outfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    Sensor *temp = l;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(ficheiro, "%11d%11d%11d%-29.29s%-29.29s", temp->id, temp->intervalo, temp->active,
                temp->local, temp->tipo);
        temp = temp->proximo;
    }

    fclose(ficheiro);
}

/* Strip trailing blanks and null terminate string */
static inline void strip_blanks(char *data, size_t size)
{
    assert(size > 0);
    size_t offset = size - 1;
    data[offset--] = '\0';
    while (offset > 0 && data[offset] == ' ')
        data[offset--] = '\0';
}

static
int CarregaTodos(Sensor **l)
{
    Sensor sens;
    FILE *ficheiro;
    int i = 0;

    ficheiro = fopen(outfile, "rt");

    if (ficheiro == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s'\n", outfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(ficheiro, "%11d%11d%11d%29c%29c", &sens.id, &sens.intervalo, &sens.active,
                  sens.local, sens.tipo) == 5)
    {
        strip_blanks(sens.local, sizeof(sens.local));
        strip_blanks(sens.tipo, sizeof(sens.tipo));
        insereSensorFim(l, novoSensor(sens.id, sens.intervalo, sens.local, sens.tipo));
    }

    fclose(ficheiro);
    return i;
}

static inline void str_copy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    assert(size > 0);
    strncpy(dst, src, size - 1);
    dst[size - 1] = '\0';
}

static
Sensor *novoSensor(int id, int tempo, char *l, char *t)
{
    Sensor *novoSensor = (Sensor *)malloc(sizeof(struct Sensor));
    if (novoSensor == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes memory\n", sizeof(struct Sensor));
        exit(1);
    }

    novoSensor->id = id;
    novoSensor->intervalo = tempo;
    str_copy(novoSensor->local, l, sizeof(novoSensor->local));
    str_copy(novoSensor->tipo, t, sizeof(novoSensor->tipo));
    novoSensor->active = 1;
    novoSensor->anterior = NULL;
    novoSensor->proximo = NULL;

    return novoSensor;
}

static
void insereSensorFim(Sensor **Lista, Sensor *novo)
{
    Sensor *atual = *Lista;

    if ((*Lista == NULL))
        *Lista = novo;
    else
    {
        while (atual->proximo != NULL)
            atual = atual->proximo;
        atual->proximo = novo;
        novo->anterior = atual;
    }
}

static void print_sensor(Sensor *sensor)
{
    printf("%5d %5d %1d [%-29s] [%-29s]\n", sensor->id, sensor->intervalo,
           sensor->active, sensor->local, sensor->tipo);
}

static void print_sensor_list(const char *tag, Sensor *list)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    while (list != 0)
    {
        print_sensor(list);
        list = list->proximo;
    }
}

static void free_sensor_list(Sensor *list)
{
    while (list != 0)
    {
        Sensor *next = list->proximo;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Sensor *list = 0;

    print_sensor_list("Empty", list);

    insereSensorFim(&list, novoSensor(10231, 23, "abc123-bothersome",  "d92-x41-ccj-92436x"));
    insereSensorFim(&list, novoSensor(20920, 25, "def456-troublesome", "e81-p42-ggk-81366x"));
    insereSensorFim(&list, novoSensor(30476, 83, "ghi789-wearisome",   "f70-q43-omm-70296x"));

    print_sensor_list("After insertion", list);
    gravaLista(list);
    free_sensor_list(list);
    list = 0;
    print_sensor_list("Emptied", list);

    CarregaTodos(&list);
    print_sensor_list("After rereading", list);

    insereSensorFim(&list, novoSensor(231,  325, "jkl012 blank laden stream",       "minimum mess or cleaning"));
    insereSensorFim(&list, novoSensor(6812, -11, "mno345 longer than was expected", "maximum type of untidiness at work"));
    print_sensor_list("After extending", list);

    free_sensor_list(list);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the output:

```
Empty:
After insertion:
10231    23 1 [abc123-bothersome            ] [d92-x41-ccj-92436x           ]
20920    25 1 [def456-troublesome           ] [e81-p42-ggk-81366x           ]
30476    83 1 [ghi789-wearisome             ] [f70-q43-omm-70296x           ]
Emptied:
After rereading:
10231    23 1 [abc123-bothersome            ] [d92-x41-ccj-92436x           ]
20920    25 1 [def456-troublesome           ] [e81-p42-ggk-81366x           ]
30476    83 1 [ghi789-wearisome             ] [f70-q43-omm-70296x           ]
After extending:
10231    23 1 [abc123-bothersome            ] [d92-x41-ccj-92436x           ]
20920    25 1 [def456-troublesome           ] [e81-p42-ggk-81366x           ]
30476    83 1 [ghi789-wearisome             ] [f70-q43-omm-70296x           ]
  231   325 1 [jkl012 blank laden stream    ] [minimum mess or cleaning     ]
 6812   -11 1 [mno345 longer than was expect] [maximum type of untidiness at]
```

The output file, `sensores.txt`, looks like this:

```
      10231         23          1abc123-bothersome            d92-x41-ccj-92436x                 20920         25          1def456-troublesome           e81-p42-ggk-81366x                 30476         83          1ghi789-wearisome             f70-q43-omm-70296x
```

When split into records, that is:

```
      10231         23          1abc123-bothersome            d92-x41-ccj-92436x           
      20920         25          1def456-troublesome           e81-p42-ggk-81366x           
      30476         83          1ghi789-wearisome             f70-q43-omm-70296x
```

The integer width of `11` allows for a negative 32-bit number in each of the first two columns.  If you know that the numbers are smaller, you can reduce the space used.  In the `scanf()`, you could omit the lengths on the integer fields; it would work the same because numeric formats automatically skip white space.  The `printf()` could add newlines; the scanning code needn't change at all because `scanf()` doesn't care about newlines when it is expecting a number (or a string — only `%c`, `%[…]` scan sets, and `%n` do not skip leading white space).

You could also arrange for some character that won't appear in the character strings (perhaps Control-A, `'\1'`) to separate the strings.  Then the scanning code could look for that and you could have variable length output.

Left to my own devices, I'd probably use a variable-length record with newline for the record delimiter, and a suitable field separator for the two strings, and a less rigid `scanf()` format.  I'd read the lines with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and then scan the lines using
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  This would work nicely unless you can have newlines in your strings.

As I put it recently in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858694/why-is-this-code-not-printing-the-lower-case-alphabet-as-expected/43957880#43957880) — lightly paraphrased:

> Read the POSIX specification of `printf()` and `scanf()` for the full details. They do have some (clearly marked) extensions over standard C `printf()` and `scanf()`, but they serve for both POSIX and standard C. Then re-read them. And re-re-read them. And do that daily for a week, and then weekly for a month, and then monthly for a year, and then yearly ever after. It will repay the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your integers when writing to the file or else they will just look like one big number to the reading function.

You could try replacing `fprintf(ficheiro, "%d%d%d%30s%30s", ...);` with `fprintf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s;%29s", ...);` (29 instead of 30 because you don't write the string terminating `'\0'`) and then should be able to read back with `fscanf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s;%29s", ...);`.

EDIT:

After writing a smaller test code and some debugging, I figured out that if you want to use `%s` in the formatting of `fscanf()` so that the white space is stripped of the end of the strings and they're `\0` terminated for you, then this would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test_save(void)
{
    FILE *ficheiro;
    ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "r+t");
    if (ficheiro == NULL) {
        ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "w+t");
    }
        fprintf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%-29s ;%-29s\n", 12, 138, 131,
        "Local_test", "Tipo_test");
        fprintf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%-29s ;%-29s\n", 21, 218, 213,
        "Local_test_2", "Second_tipo_test");
    fclose(ficheiro);
}

void test_read(void)
{
    FILE *ficheiro;
    ficheiro = fopen("sensores.txt", "r+t");
    if (ficheiro == NULL) {
        printf("no file %s\n", "sensores.txt");
        return;
    }
    int id, intervalo, active;
    char local[30], tipo[30];

    while (fscanf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s ;%29s\n", &id, &intervalo, &active,
            local, tipo) == 5) {
        printf("id: %d intervalo: %d active: %d\tlocal: [%s]\ttipo: [%s]\n",
                id, intervalo, active, local, tipo);
    }
    fclose(ficheiro);
}

int main(void)
{
    test_save();
    test_read();
}
```

Output of this test program:

```
id: 12 intervalo: 138 active: 131   local: [Local_test] tipo: [Tipo_test]  
id: 21 intervalo: 218 active: 213   local: [Local_test_2]   tipo: [Second_tipo_test]
```

As seen by the file writen by this test-program, each record is writen in one line:

```
12;138;131;Local_test                    ;Tipo_test                    
21;218;213;Local_test_2                  ;Second_tipo_test
```

Comment: i just tried that but its still not printing anything.
about the `\0` how should i add it?

im guessing its not like this `fscanf(ficheiro, "%d;%d;%d;%29s\0;%29s\0"`

Comment: The code should probably use a delimiter — newline would be sensible — to mark the end of each record.  As it stands, there's no way to tell the end of one record from the start of the next.

Comment: The scanning `%29s` only works reliably if there are no spaces in the strings.  The output should probably specify `%29s` too.  I think `%29c` is the best choice, but you have to add the null terminator because `scanf()` won't.  Also, `printf()` doesn't print null bytes unless you force its hand with `printf("%c", '\0');` or equivalent.  You must use `%c` and pass the null byte as an argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if i know for certain that the strings wont have spaces it should be ok to leave it as `%30s` right?
also im starting to get confused about 29 or 30.
atm i have `char[30]` on the struct and `%30s` on both the `fprintf` and `fscanf`. where should i edit to `29`? and thanks for your time, it really is appreciated

Comment: While the structures elements are of size 30, you must use 29 in the `scanf()` calls to avoid overflow.  When you use 30 in the `printf()` calls, you are adding at least one blank to the string (and it is at the start unless you use `"%-30s"`!). You can add a blank to the scanning format to skip an arbitrary number of whites space characters — zero or more of them. However, the `%29s` for `scanf()` would skip leading spaces anyway.  In case you haven't noticed, getting this stuff right is *really* hard.  Be cautious!

Answer (score 0):

1. `fprintf(ficheiro, "%d%d%d%30s%30s"`... I suggest you put a delimiter, say coma or #. Imagine, your id is 11, intervalo is 10, when saved, it's 1110. How do you know, when reading from the file, the id is 11 instead of 1 or 111?
2. change `insereSensorFim(&l,` to `insereSensorFim(l,`
3. In insereSensorFim, you use a while loop to find the tail, it's not efficient. Let *Lista always points to the tail and skip the loop. For example,

```
    void insereSensorFim(Sensor** tail, Sensor* novo) {
        if (*tail != NULL)
        {
            (*tail)->proximo = novo;
            novo->anterior = (*tail);
        }
        *tail = nova;
    }
```

Comment: already had fixed the 2 first points (that `&`...)
also thanks for the advice on the insereSensorFim :)